# How do we know inference rules are correct?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, axioms, natural-deduction

I know **axioms** are statements which are assumed to be true (meaning that axioms are not proved).

**Theorems** are statements which can be proved or has been proved. In the proofs of theorems we can use axioms, previously proven theorems and inference rules.

**Inference rules** is the part where I am a little bit confused. Do inference rules need to be proved or are they assumed to be true like axioms are? My understanding is inference rules are assumed to be true, but I am not sure at ALL!

**If inference rules need to be proved** then let's take for example Natural Deduction Calculus:

- Axioms: A\/~A; A=>A

How would I prove for example these inference rules:

1. Conjunction elimination: A /\B |- A,B
2. Implication elimination/Modus ponens: A, A=>B |- B

Comment: Use the semantics for the basic connectives in order to prove that rules are *sound* (or *correct*), i e they preserve truth.

Comment: In the case of $(\land \text E)$ the proof is elementary: if $A \land B$ is true, by truth table for $\land$, both $A$ and $B$ must be true. The same for $(\to \text E)$ (MP).

Comment: Gotcha, so I basically need to prove (1) A/\B |= A,B by means of truth table or some other method. In this case the calculus is sound and complete, so provability 
coincides with logical entailment (A/\B |- A,B coincides with A/\B |= A,B). But what if provability did NOT coincide with logical entailment? How I would go about proving it?

Comment: @user859v What if *what* was not the case? Do you mean: what if provability does not coincide with logical entailment? Well, if the proof system is unsound, then that is because the rules do not reflect valid inferences. And you would show that using semantics. And to show that the rules are sound, you would use semantics. And to show that the axioms reflect true logical principles (like $A \lor \neg A$) you would use semantics. And to show that some axiom like $A \lor B$ does not reflect a logical truth, you would use semantics. :) So, you always use semantics for these kinds of things

Comment: @Bram28 Yes, sorry that was what I meant

Comment: @user859v Just expanded my comment ...

Comment: Thank you guys! now everything is clear to me :)

Comment: You can think of axioms as special inference rules with no premises. Like axioms, inference rules are assumed, but you can prove soundness by showing that they are semantically valid inferences if you replace $\vdash$ by $\vDash$.

Answer (score -1):

I take the example of modus ponens. You have to prove that $\forall A\forall B, A=>(A=>B)=>B$.